# Помощь с работой БД и Swing

Tags: java

Кто-то сможет объяснить, буду очень благодарен.

Интересует вопрос, как в "GUI Form" , считать значения с textField и занести в БД.

Вот мой код:

```
package diplom.First;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.sql.*;
;
/**
 * Created by Nika on 26.01.2017.
 */
public class BD  extends JFrame {
    private JPanel panel;
    private JButton button1;
    private JButton Button2;
    private JButton Button3;
    private JTextField textField1;
    private JTextField textField2;
    private JTextField textField3;
    private JButton Button4;
    public static Connection conn;
    public static Statement statmt;
    public static ResultSet resSet;
    public BD()   {
        setContentPane(panel);
        panel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(1300,1300));
        setVisible(true);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        button1.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                try {
                    Conn();
                }
                catch (Exception u)
                {}
            }
        });
        Button2.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                try {
                    CreateDB();
                }
                catch (Exception u)
                {
                    System.out.println (u);
                }
            }
        });
        Button3.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                try {
                    ReadDB();
                }
                catch (Exception u)
                {}
            }
        });
        Button4.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                String Name =  textField1.getText();
                int phone = Integer.parseInt(textField2.getText());
                int age = Integer.parseInt(textField3.getText());
                System.out.println(phone+""+age+""+Name);
            }
        });
    }
    // --------ПОДКЛЮЧЕНИЕ К БАЗЕ ДАННЫХ--------
    public static void Conn() throws ClassNotFoundException, SQLException
    {
        conn = null;
        Class.forName("org.sqlite.JDBC");
        conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlite:TEST1.s3db");
        System.out.println("База Подключена!");
    }
    // --------Создание таблицы--------
    public void CreateDB() throws ClassNotFoundException, SQLException
    {
        statmt = conn.createStatement();
        statmt.execute("CREATE TABLE if not exists 'users' ('id' INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, 'name' text, 'phone' INT, 'age' INT);");
        String name =  textField1.getText();
        int phone = Integer.parseInt(textField2.getText());
        int age = Integer.parseInt(textField3.getText());
        //statmt.execute("INSERT INTO 'users' ('name', 'phone','age') VALUES (textField1.getText(), Integer.parseInt(textField2.getText()),Integer.parseInt(textField3.getText())) ");
        //statmt.execute("INSERT INTO 'users' ('name', 'phone','age') VALUES (name, phone,age) ");
        statmt.execute("INSERT INTO 'users' ('name', 'phone','age') VALUES ('Vasya', 121,2313) ");
        System.out.println("Таблица создана или уже существует.");
    }
    // -------- Вывод таблицы--------
    public static void ReadDB() throws ClassNotFoundException, SQLException
    {
        resSet = statmt.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM users");
        while(resSet.next())
        {
            int id = resSet.getInt("id");
            String  name = resSet.getString("name");
            String  phone = resSet.getString("phone");
            String  age = resSet.getString("age");
            System.out.println( "ID = " + id );
            System.out.println( "name = " + name );
            System.out.println( "phone = " + phone );
            System.out.println( "age = " + age );
            System.out.println();
        }
        System.out.println("Таблица выведена");
        resSet.close();
        conn.close();
        statmt.close();
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new BD();
    }
}
```

Пробовал так и так, но в первом случае оно так не канает выдает ошибку

```
statmt.execute("INSERT INTO 'users' ('name', 'phone','age') VALUES (textField1.getText(), Integer.parseInt(textField2.getText()),Integer.parseInt(textField3.getText()))
```

> "java.sql.SQLException: [SQLITE_ERROR] SQL error or missing database
>   (near "(": syntax error)"

Тут просто не видит этих переменных.

```
statmt.execute("INSERT INTO 'users' ('name', 'phone','age') VALUES (name, phone,age)
```

Тема совершенно новая, буду рад если подробно, и понятно объясните. Спасибо.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если ты именно так и добавляешь, то не правильно, пробуй так:

```
statmt.execute("INSERT INTO `users` (`name`, `phone`, `age`) VALUES ('" + textField1.getText() + "', '" + Integer.parseInt(textField2.getText()) + "', '" + Integer.parseInt(textField3.getText() + "');");
```

Comment: Попробую , задавайте

Comment: Да спасибо так работает, остались вопросы, можете объяснить. ' "+ text+" '   - Как это работает, ибо недавно начал. Как я разобрался в одинарных кавычках отображают наши поля или текстовое значение. Но зачем двойные? И зачем нам по бокам текстЕдита ставить "+", ведь мы с помощью (',') разделяем поля куда заносятся наши данные. Надеюсь вы поняли мысль, что хочу я у вас спросить, ибо чёт туго описать))

Comment: П.С: Хочу с помощью "Enter" перейти на след.строку, а оно отправляет сообщение)

Comment: Могу предположить, они служат на подобие, не экранизированных символов.

Comment: Вы ведь строки изучали? В внутри execute, вы передаете строку. Чтобы вставить в строку какие либо данные с переменной , необходимо закрывать строку двойными кавичками , ставить '+' , далее имя переменной , затем опять '+' и открываем двойные кавычки если хотим дописать строку.

Comment: Вы не перейдете на следующую строку, ибо используете textfield . Почитайте об textarea.

Comment: Так, наши поля мы отмечаем (' ',' ') , в данном случае в одном поле будет лежать переменная со значением String,  в другом int.  Для использования строки я должен записать к примеру "Masha", но если я хочу дописать строку к примеру так: "Masha"+" "+"devochka"+" ".  Для int  я могу просто записать число, к примеру 10. Теперь, зачем мне ставить +текст+, если я сюда больше ничего дописывать не буду,а (' ',), мы переходим на новое поле и там другая строка с другим типом переменной.

Comment: Дальше, вверху мы написали что это поле будет с типом int, зачем мы его должны брать в кавычки, почему не можем записать так: ' Integer.parseInt(textField2.getText()) '?  Не совсем понятно, ваше последнее сообщение. Извините за дотошность, просто хочу понять)

Comment: Потому что это переменные. Просто так, вставить переменную в строку, нельзя. Необходимо вокруг переменной добавлять +.

Comment: То что там будет другая строка, никому не понятно. Это вы знаете, а программа лишь получает готовую строку и отдает на выполнение в саму базу данных или еще как.

Comment: Вы говорили, что по нажатию enter хотели перейти на новую строку. Я подумал, что вы это делаете в text field поле